# How to persist but avoid unique keys exceptions?

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0

My problem is simple: 
A `user` has an `address`, `address` is composed of `city`, `state` and `country`.

So for that I have this structure:

```
public class User {
  ..
  //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserAddress
  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinColumn(name="id_user_address")
  private UserAddress userAddress;
  ..
}
```

Note that `CascadeType` **does not** have `CascadeType.ALL` because if the user is deleted it won't affect the `cities, states and countries` created.

```
public class UserAddress {
  ..
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AddressCity
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.})
    @JoinColumn(name="id_city")
    private AddressCity addressCity;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AddressCountry
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="id_country")
    private AddressCountry addressCountry;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AddressState
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="id_state")
    private AddressState addressState;
  ..
}
```

My problem is if I try to register a user that has the same `city` for example it gives me an exception:

> SEVERE: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Campinas' for key 'city_UNIQUE'

How can I avoid this kind of `constraint`, keeping the `CASCADE`?
And anyone know how to show the queries made by JPA in my JSF project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CascadeType.PERSIST` annotation for `User.userAddress` causes `userAddress` to be persisted for each `User` persisted and `CascadeType.PERSIST` annotation for `UserAddress.addressCity` causes `addressCity` to be persisted for each `UserAddress` persisted. Thus when you persist a user with same city, new city is tried to be persisted with the same key which causes constraint violation. So remove the cascades for those ManyToOne annotated relationships.

You have to check on saving User whether userAddress already exists and check on saving UserAddress whether the relationships inside it already exist and take required action.